# Find out if I can ask for more

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

**Scenario:**

I have a system that issues requests to another system.

Each of these requests have a probability $p$ of requiring a specialized resource.
The probability $p$ can be estimated using a Poisson distribution.

If a request completes and none of the specialized resources are available, the request is considered FAILED.

**Extra info available:**

If it makes any different to the solution, I also have the following:

Each request can follow one of 3 distributions of time to complete before timeout $T$.

1. Most taking a very short time $(\leq\frac{T}{30})$ with very few taking longer.
2. Timeout for most with a few taking shorter.
3. A binomial distribution around $T/2$. These are the ones that require the specialized resources.

If it helps, I also have the probabilities of each of the 3 distributions.

**Question:**

Given I know $p$, $T$ and the currently number of outstanding requests (and how long they have taken) and current number of available specialized resources. How can I calculate the probability of failure if I am to add one more outstanding request?

Alternatively, given the above plus a $p_{error}$ that is the maximum accepted level of failure (over time, it can surpass it in small intervals), how can I calculate the maximum number of outstanding requests I can have right now.

Approximate functions are fine for my purpose, as long as it works where the number of available specialized resources is 1 to 20. Even better if it takes into account the actual failure rate and adjusts, so the actual failure rate is always below $p_{error}$. $p$ is estimated to be in the range of 10% to 66%. $p_{error}$ is estimated to be <10%.

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... It was as simple as using excels

```
POISSON.DIST(number of available resources,p*Number of outstanding requests,TRUE)
```

Which can be implemented using the incomplete gamma function outside of excel.